# Changing bar order when using stat_summary with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I change the order in this plot based on the values of column?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

This example should help you. You just need the `reorder`

Based on R documentation:

> reorder is a generic function. The "default" method treats its first
>   argument as a categorical variable, and reorders its levels based on
>   the values of a second variable, usually numeric.

```
library(ggplot2)
dt<-data.frame("Name"=c("A","B","C","D","E"),value=sample(5))

ggplot(dt, aes( x= reorder(Name, value) , y= value))+
  geom_col(stat='identity', aes(fill=Name), width=.5)
```

The result is:

[image]